# Neo4J Cypher: return some attributes only if rowcount is less than a threshold

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have got a cypher-query like this one:

```
match (s)-[r]-(m) 
  where s.id='...' and r.id='...' 
  return s.id as id, s.title as title, s.content as content
```

What I would like to achieve is to return the (potentially very large) value of s.content only if the total rowcount is less than a given threshold (5 for example).

I tried

```
match (s:mytype)-[r:myothertype]-(m:mytype) 
  where s.id='...' and r.id='...' 
  return s.id as id, s.title as title, 
  case
    when count(*) < 5 s.content
    else null 
  end as content
```

This query seems to be syntactically correct, but it takes forever to come back and eventually tears down my server, even with just 10 nodes and 4 relationships in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanx in advance,

Jens

P.S. Just to make it clear: I do not want to limit the results. I need id and title for all nodes in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that could be causing your performance issues, but it depends a lot on your data. You've generalized in your example, but let's assume you have not set an index on your properties for `x.id`.

Run the following query to set the index on label `mytype` for property `id`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :mytype(id)
```

Then please try this optimized query. The issue is likely that for each `s` node you are performing an aggregation on count for the entire collection. This seems computationally expensive.

```
MATCH (s:mytype { id: '...' })
MATCH (s)-[r:myothertype { id: '...'}]-(:mytype)
WITH count(*) as content_weight
MATCH (s:mytype { id: '...' })
MATCH (s)-[r:myothertype { id: '...'}]-(:mytype)
WITH s, content_weight,
     (CASE
        WHEN content_weight < 5 THEN s.content
        ELSE null 
      END) as content
RETURN s.id, s.title, content
```

Update: You'll see two matches going on here. There is another way to do this query using an upcoming feature in Cypher. For now, this query should perform fine. The correct way to do this would be to collect on `s`, to get the collection length, and then to unwind the collection back to rows with the content weight. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: I have 100M records in my neoj4 instance and it fails whenever I try co do `count()` on a rather large dataset. I wouldn't recommend sticking to this idiom unless you are totally sure your system can handle this.

Comment: There is no problem with running `count()` on a large dataset using Cypher in Neo4j 2.0 GA. If you are having an issue please open up a question here on Stackoverflow or a support ticket if you are a Neo4j customer.

Comment: I'm telling you, there *is* an issue. When I run `start n = node(*) return count(*)` via the web-interface, the server hangs up *completely*. And I'm not the only one who experiences this.

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not work for me. I already had an index set on the id and tried to seperate the parts of the query by using `this`, but this always leads to `content_weight` being 1. It does not seem to depend on how many rows are returned. When I return `count(s)` without the `this` the number of the rows returned is stored there... I cannot say that i understand how this works so far. At least your query is not tearing down my server and returns within a few milliseconds.

Comment: cdshines -- Ok, I do understand you are having a problem, but please just open up a new question and someone will solve it for you. It doesn't help to put it here, it's non-constructive to this thread. Thanks.

Comment: jens -- Ah yes, that's my fault. Let me update the query. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Kenny - works like a charm. Thank you very much. You can even leave out the first `MATCH` after the first `WITH`. BTW: Is this a wise way to handle this from a performance point of view or would it be better to fire two queries (if the result-size of the first one is small enough).

Comment: jens -- Excellent, good to hear it worked. Until Cypher allows unwinding a collection (reverse of COLLECT) then the double match is the only way to do it for this scenario. Definitely more performant to do 2 matches in a single query rather than 2 requests. :)